# SocketChannel.write() writing problem

Tags: java, nio

The issue here is I can see that the data is being written out to the socket but it is not ALWAYS being sent.

Here's a code sniplet

```
ByteBuffer writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
writeBuffer.clear();
writeBuffer.put("heartbeat".getBytes());


writeBuffer.flip();
LOG.debug("is connected: " + socketChannel.isConnected());
int bytesWritten = 0;
if (key.isWritable()) {
    while (writeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        bytesWritten += socketChannel.write(writeBuffer);
    }
}
```

I use TCPMon to see if the actual data gets written out to the socket - WHICH it does.

But using WireShark (another network monitoring tool) I cannot see the packet going through the NIC.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is wrong anyway. If the write returns zero the socket send buffer is full, so you should register OP_WRITE and return to the select loop, rather than waste time spinning until there is room again. Your present technique starves the other channels of service and wastes CPU cycles.

Also, testing `isConnected()` at this point is futile. It is. You connected it. That method tells you about the state of the socket, not the connection.

Comment: I do register OP_WRITE (emitted from above code), otherwise key.isWritable() would return false. Anyway, bytesWritten so far ALWAYS returns > 0 and has never been stuck in a loop .. yet. Also for some reason my previous comments have been removed.

Comment: Although I do agree hasRemaining() is evil - that I will refactor.

Comment: @Vueey the code is still wrong. One day you will encounter a full socket send buffer, and the problems I described will immediately occur. In fact this is the only actual use for OP_WRITE: to tell you when space has become available in the socket send buffer, and it is only useful to use it after you have encountered a full buffer. The rest of the time you can just write immediately.

Comment: EJP: I don't get it either. I also get awaken by a select() call returning and channel's selection key having "OP_WRITE" in its readyOps field. So, I would naturally expect that the next call to channel.write(bufs); would not return 0... but it still does.

Comment: @Vueey `hasRemaining()` is not 'evil': I didn't say so; and I don't think so. Don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: @kellogs Can't explain that. Never seen it in 20 years of NIO programming. Did you clear the selected-key set every time around the `select()` loop? This is important.

Answer (score -1):

Try it as follows

```
/**
 * @param socketChannel
 * @param buf
 * @return no. of bytes written to the socket
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static int writeByteBuffer(SocketChannel socketChannel, ByteBuffer buf) throws IOException {

    boolean blocking = socketChannel.isBlocking();
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    int totalWritten = 0;
    try {

        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // pass SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE for read and
        // write
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

        selector.select();

        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();

        Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

        outerOfWriting: while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

            SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();

            boolean writable = key.isWritable();

            if (writable) {

                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                boolean hasRemaining = false;
                while (hasRemaining = buf.hasRemaining()) {
                    int written = channel.write(buf);
                    totalWritten += written;

                    if (written == 0) {                         
                        selector.select();
                        selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                        keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
                        continue outerOfWriting;
                    }
                }

                if (!hasRemaining) {
                    key.cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    } finally {
        try {
            selector.close();
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(blocking);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return totalWritten;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        ByteBuffer writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
        writeBuffer.clear();
        writeBuffer.put("heartbeat".getBytes());
        writeBuffer.flip();

        SocketChannel socketChannel = null;//initialize
        writeByteBuffer(socketChannel, writeBuffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? Why would you close the selector just because the socket send buffer is full? There is no point to this, and it certainly doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP if the buffer is full (i.e. written == 0) then I'm trying to register a new selector so the previous one needs to be cancelled and closed.

Comment: I can see that. I asked you *why*, and you haven't answered. It's pointless. You don't need a new selector. This accomplishes exactly nothing.

Comment: @EJP I thought registering new selector will avail new send buffer size so that it will make the writing faster, but you are right it has no effect. I have removed that unwanted code now. I had faced a performance issue in linux machine, the writing was very slow even for a 300KB of data and `channel.write` was frequently returning `0` so I  came to thought registering new selector will improve writing speed.

Comment: You are mistaken. The selector has nothing to do with the socket send buffer size. At the native level, the selector doesn't even exist: it is it's an artefact of the Java NIO API; so recreating it can't have any effect whatsoever except to waste time.  Was there some reason you didn't give this reasoning in your answer? Or when you were asked, two days ago?